# Alexa skill failing to play MP3 on first execution after a period of being inactivity. Works fine if regularly called

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, alexa-skills-kit

I have created an alexa skill that uses API gateway and a lambda function to take multiple MP3 files and combine them into a single MP3 for gapless playback in the skill. It works like this:

**SSML request:**

```
<speak> <audio src='https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/alpha/files?file=file1.mp3file=file2.mp3file=file3.mp3'/> </speak>
```

Steps:

- The SSML request in the Alexa skill is routed to my python lambda function via API gateway.
- The lambda function uses ffmpeg to combine the mp3 files and returns an HTTP header containing the single mp3 file to API gateway.
- The skill plays the combined audio response as part of a SSML speak function.

This all works but, **not the first time the function is called after a period of inactivity** (i'm trying to detemine how long the inactivity period needs to be - it's certainly a number of minutes). The skill responds with:

```
I'm having trouble connecting to the audio file URI
```

If I immediately rerun my skill, the mp3 file is processed correctly and the audio plays as expected. The skill then works as expected until it is again left inactive for a period of time.

So:

time 00m:00s : "Alexa, open "skill name"

```
I'm having trouble connecting to the audio file URI
```

time 00m:10s : "Alexa, open "skill name"

```
Hello, welcome to your skill.... (mp3 file plays)
```

*<period of inactivity e.g. 30 minutes)*

time 30m:00  : "Alexa, open "skill name"

```
I'm having trouble connecting to the audio file URI
```

time 30m:10s : "Alexa, open "skill name"

```
Hello, welcome to your skill.... (mp3 file plays)
```

All of the cloudwatch logs for API gateway and my lamda function look correct both when the skill works and when it doesn't (the mp3 file is always generated and returned by api gateway). There is no error reported in the log for the Alexa skill - but I may need to add more debugging to find it?

I'm guessing that there is a delay in the lambda function being loaded and executed on the first run, and the Alexa skill is timing out without giving enough time for the URL to respond. Does this sound feasible? Any suggestions to increase timeouts/ensure a response is received before a function completes etc?

Comment: Hard to say without understanding how your lambda is written, what method of await response you generate. Something else to look at is allocated timeout and memory you are providing the lambda. lastly I guess drill into the lambda logs especially if you are "blending" the audio each time on the ffly.

Comment: Thanks Chuck.  Could you elaborate on what you mean regarding the await response?  I have found that if I increase the memory allocation from the default 128MB to 640MB then the problem seems to go away.  However, the lambda report for each execution reports: (Size: 640 MB Max Memory Used: 115 MB) so why would more memory have helped?

Comment: you indicated that you are using ffmpeg in the lambda to stitch the mp3 together, by increasing the capacity of the spot you are calling, it is helping eliminate the problem, when I was asking how you await the response, I literally meant when you call the function it operates async. if the function call isn't waited for it would fail.